# Ionic application does not work on Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: ionic-framework

I created and published the application on Ionic, but I have a problem with installation on Samsung Galaxy S7 (Android 6, Exynos proc.). The application isn't installed and doesn't give error messages. Has someone else faced such problems?

Comment: Did you check in Gap debugger ?

Comment: I have problems with styles in Samsung s7 . I think that is top or margin-top styles in samsung s7 not working.. But my application run well